# Print the String that match the number in Array

Tags: java, arrays, match

I am trying to take out only one value from String list(Array) that corresponds user's input(number). If a user input number 4 the result should be 60. Here is the code that i've been trying to finish. Error is incompatible int and string(of course), but other than that i am sure i made mistakes somewhere else as well. I would like array to be as simple as possible without objects and classes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindStringValue{
public static void main(String[] args){


  final int[] VALID_NUMBERS=new int[8];
  String[] someArray = {"20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90"};

  int inputNumber;
  boolean foundIt=false;
  int x=0;

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter a number from 0-7 >> ");
  inputNumber = in.nextInt();

  for(x=0;x<VALID_NUMBERS.length;++x)
        if(x==(someArray[x])){
        foundIt=true;
        break;}
        System.out.println("The Number "+inputNumber+" corresponds to String  "+someArray[x]);

        }
              }
```

Comment: Please post the exact error you're seeing.

Comment: When you write `if(x==(someArray[x]))`, you're comparing a String with an integer. Are you sure that's what you intended to do?

Comment: No, actually when it loops through and match the number then to stop and print the value that corresponds the number... so if i put 3, to stop and print on the screen "The number 3 corresponds to String 50"

Comment: So if x=3, stop(exit the loop), print on the screen 50

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misreading the question, but it sounds like all you want is:

```
if(inputNumber >= 0 && inputNumber < someArray.length) {
  System.out.printf("The Number %d corresponds to String %s\n", inputNumber, someArray[inputNumber]);
} else {
  // you don't really show how you want to handle this case...
}
```

It's not clear what the purpose of VALID_NUMBERS is.

#### Edit

I meant you should replace the for loop completely:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FindStringValue {

  final String[] someArray = {"20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90"};

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number from 0-7 >> ");
    int inputNumber = in.nextInt();

    if(inputNumber >= 0 && inputNumber < someArray.length) {
      System.out.printf("The Number %d corresponds to String %s\n", inputNumber, someArray[inputNumber]);
    } else {
      // you don't really show how you want to handle this case...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably i did not explain good. I copied your code into mine and actually it is good but the result is this Enter a number from 0-7 >> 4
The Number 4 corresponds to String 60
The Number 4 corresponds to String 60
The Number 4 corresponds to String 60
The Number 4 corresponds to String 60
The Number 4 corresponds to String 60
The Number 4 corresponds to String 60
The Number 4 corresponds to String 60
The Number 4 corresponds to String 60
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
 at FindStringValue.main(FindStringValue.java:25)
What i would like is the result..

Comment: ...result to be in one line  "The number 4 corresponds to String 60". And if i type 5 it would be "The number 5 corresponds to String 70"

Comment: with VALID_NUMBER i was just declaring 8 memory spaces for array elements so that it could cycle in the loop until it hits the right String. Maybe i am wrong with that...

Comment: Ok i see now. Basically i dont need loop for this code. I was thinking that i needed to use loop to cycle through array list and then when it finds that String to stop and print out the result. This was helpful, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to go over the array and do any comparison since you have the element index to be removed .You can achieve your goal by the following snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] someArray = {"20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90"};

    int inputNumber;
    boolean foundIt = false;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number from 0-7 >> ");
    inputNumber = in.nextInt();
    in.close();
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(someArray));
    list.remove(inputNumber);
    String []newArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    System.out.println("The Number " + inputNumber + " corresponds to String  " + someArray[inputNumber]);
}
```

Comment: This is good way as well. I just need to play more with this code since i am new to arrays. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do away with the array altogether and just use a List as shown here.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90");

    int inputNumber;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number from 0-7 >> ");
    inputNumber = in.nextInt();
    in.close();

    if(inputNumber < numbers.size()) //validity check of input value
    {
        System.out.println("The Number "+ inputNumber + " corresponds to String  "+ numbers.get(inputNumber));
    }

 }
```